# Subtleties of SQL Server Variables

Tags: t-sql, variables, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following SQL Server stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ispsDcOhcAgg @TmpTableName NVARCHAR(50), @ListItem NVARCHAR(50) 
AS
IF EXISTS (SELECT name 
           FROM sys.tables 
           WHERE name = @TmpTableName) 
DROP TABLE @TmpTableName; -- This will not work.
GO
```

This will clearly not work (see the comment in the above snippit). The only (and very ugly) way I have found to get around this problem is to do the following

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ispsDcOhcAgg @TmpTableName NVARCHAR(50), @ListItem NVARCHAR(50) 
AS
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(4000) 
SET @SQL = N'IF EXISTS (SELECT name ' +
           N'FROM sys.tables ' + 
           N'WHERE name = N' + N'''' + @TmpTableName + N''') ' + 
           N'DROP TABLE ' + @TmpTableName + N';'
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
GO
```

which truly stinks and for large stored procedures, it's horrendous!

**Is there another way of doing this that I don't know about?**

Thanks for your time.

Comment: No, there is no other way than using dynamic SQL to achieve this.

Comment: The `if exists` part works fine as an inline statement with a variable, its just a `where` clause, just the `drop` needs to be executed dynamically if the condition is met

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, if you want to use a table name dynamically like this, you need to use dynamic SQL.

So you should make sure you don't open yourself up to nasty SQL injection risks!

Try something like this:

```
SET @SQL = 'IF EXISTS (SELECT name ' +
           N'FROM sys.tables ' + 
           N'WHERE name = @TableName) ' + 
           N'DROP TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(@TmpTableName) + ';'

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@TableName sysname', @TmpTableName;
```

Answer (score 2):

No, if you want to determine the table to be dropped at runtime, there is no alternative to dynamic SQL.

There is a *slightly* less ugly way: you only use dynamic SQL for the command that needs to be dynamic (the `DROP` command):

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(100) 
IF EXISTS (SELECT name 
       FROM sys.tables 
       WHERE name = @TmpTableName) 
BEGIN
    SET @SQL = N'DROP TABLE ' + @TmpTableName + N';'
    EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
END
```